# Is it possible to map multiple ports to the same container port

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to map multiple ports in Kubernetes to the same container port within a deployment? I know this is possible in Docker, for example

`docker run -tid -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3000 nginx`

I have not been able to find any documentation for this use case within a Kubernetes deployment. The reason I need this is to bypass mTLS in my liveness probe without changing my backend webapp container, where the service and healthcheck endpoints are hosted on port 3000.

Comment: Kubernetes does not do anything with ports in a pod: whatever your app binds to - will be exposed exactly. You can make traffic flow through different ports using services: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/ but it does not look like it will help you. Nonetheless, to answer your very question: no, you cannot remap ports in containers in a pod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @zerkms commented, it is not possible to map host ports to container ports in the same way that docker does.

To fix my mTLS/healthcheck problem, I created a curl container called `liveness` inside my pod and set the liveness container's healthcheck to be of type exec that curls localhost on my app's port for the healthcheck endpoint.